Whats missing on my code for not adding the objects to my ArrayList?
I'm trying to make a simple program just to learn more about OOP but I can't see whats missing on my code for not being able to add an item to my ArrayList. Could you have a look and briefly explain whats missing here? Thank you very much!
Main:
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();

        ui.start();
        System.out.println(calc.getNumbers());

    }
}

User interface:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInterface {

    private Calculator calculator;
    private Scanner scanner;

    public UserInterface() {
        calculator = new Calculator();
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void start() {

        int input;

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Enter point totals, -1 stops:");
            input = scanner.nextInt();

            if (input == -1) {
                break;
            }

            if (input >= 0 && input <= 100) {
                calculator.addNumber(input);
            }
        }
    }
}


Calculator:
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Calculator {

    private final ArrayList<Integer> numbers;

    public Calculator() {
        numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addNumber(int number) {
        numbers.add(number);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }
}


I made the method and was working within the same class but when I wanted to split it into two classes the object isn't adding it, chatgpt tells me the code its fine and it should add my item.
It's expected to add the item to my ArrayList so I can make a calculator classes aside from the UI.

Pass the Calculator instance to UserInterface via constructor in main.

UserInterface#calculator and local variable calc are two independent instances. Changing one does not affect the other.

The concept that you're missing is that of "object state", which is simplistically is what are the values held by the variables of an object. In Java, each object has its own unique state, and changing the state of one object does not automatically change the state of another. So, if you create more than one Calculator object and change the state of one (for example, add data to its ArrayList), then the state of the other Calculator object, the one that you display, remains unchanged. This is a key core Java concept that you will want to study and understand well.

You're creating a new Calculator inside the UserInterface constructor.
        UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();

...

    public UserInterface() {
        calculator = new Calculator();
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

should be
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        UserInterface ui = new UserInterface(calc);

...

    public UserInterface(Calculator calculator) {
        this.calculator = calculator;
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

Alternatively you could add a getCalculator() method to UserInterface, and not create it in Main.
